# Get last </td></tr> with regular expression?

Tags: html, regex

I need to get all tags between last `</td>` and the closing `</tr>` in each row. The regular expression I use `<\/TD\s*>(.*?)<\/TR\s*>` retrieve all from first `</TD>` till last `</TR>` - marked with bold on sample below.

```
<TABLE>
 <TR><TD>TD11**</TD><TD>TD12</TD><TD>TD13</TD><SPAN><FONT>test1</FONT></SPAN></TR>**
 <TR><TD>TD21**</TD><TD>TD22</TD><TD>TD23</TD><SPAN><FONT>test2</FONT></SPAN></TR>**
</TABLE>
```

But a what I really need is

```
<TABLE>
 <TR><TD>TD11</TD><TD>TD12</TD><TD>TD13**</TD><SPAN><FONT>test1</FONT></SPAN></TR>**
 <TR><TD>TD21</TD><TD>TD22</TD><TD>TD23**</TD><SPAN><FONT>test2</FONT></SPAN></TR>**
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what do you want from that table? What "between last in each row" means?

Comment: Psst... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: If you want an easy solution that is maintainable, you don't want to use a regex for this. If this is just a personal programming exercise because, say, Climbing Mt. Everest while naked and tripping balls is just not AWESOME enough for you, well then, try to use a regex. But, really, you don't want to use a regex for this.

Answer (score 2):

Its not recommended to use regular expressions to parse HTML, html is non regular and there for notoriously unreliable when trying to use regular expressions.

Heres a good blog post explaining the logic and offering alternatives:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not solve my problem. I absolutely agreed it's bad idea, but such HTML returns by MS Word during Cope-Paste and I need to remove this tag between </TD> </TR> to made view looks correct. And customers doesn't user JQuery. So, this is hard fix which will be replaced in future with better solution. But now I just need to replace this in so many places, and regEx is good way for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
</TD>((?:(?!</T[DR]>).)*)</TR>
```

The regex *starts* to match at the first `</TD>`, but fails as soon as it reaches the second `</TD>` because of the `(?!</T[DR]>).`, which matches any character that's not the first character of a `</TD>` or `</TR>` tag.  That's optional because of the enclosing `(?:...)*`, so it tries to match the next part of the regex, which is `</TR>`.  That fails too, so the match attempt is abandoned.

It tries again starting at the second `</TD>` and fails again.  Finally, it starts matching at the *third* `</TD>` and successfully matches from there to the first `</TR>`.

You may want to specify "single-line" or "dot-matches-all" mode, in case there are newlines that didn't show in your example.  You didn't specify a regex flavor, so I can't say exactly how to do that.